# In pytorch torchscript, how to define mutiple entry point

Tags: pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime, torchscript

Have a torch model as follow :

```
  MyModel
       update(self)    :  Update some params.
       predict(self,X) :  Predict with some input tensor.
```

When exporting to torchscript, is there a way to have 2 entry points:

```
One for  update()
One for predict()
```

Comment: if you have a function `update()` in your code, try annotating it with `@torch.jit.export`, then you can call it from the scripted module